# How to prevent the loss of Tooltip when using ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, version-9

Version 9, windows 7:

When I use `ListLinePlot` Tooltip does not work any more. It seems to have been lost somewhere. With same data, Tooltip works ok using `ListPlot`.

```
data = Table[Tooltip[{x, x^2}], {x, 0, 10, .1}];
ListPlot[data]
(* Tooltip shows ok *)

ListLinePlot[data]
(* Tooltip does not show up *)
```

[image]

Looked at possible issues for `ListLinePlot` and do not seen mention of this.

question: How to make Tooltip work with `ListLinePlot`

thanks

Comment: I get tool-tips from `ListLinePlot` in version 7.  Should this be tagged `version-9`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it will get lost even in the case of `ListPlot` if you go to continuous solid line case:

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

In both cases the fix is to bring back points somehow, for example using `Mesh`:

```
ListLinePlot[data, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0]]
```

OR any similar trick in that manner:

```
Show[ListLinePlot[data], ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]]]
```

The reason for this is probably the fact that in bare solid-line case you get only line segments in resulting `Graphics` primitives (check with `InputForm[..."your plot"...]`). And line segments are wrong to wrap `Point` tool-tips around.

@MikeHoneychurch recommendation will work too; if you want to see only the solid line (with no point marks) something like empty string this will do

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> ""]
```

To answer Mike's comment on `Tooltip` on line segments - it does work if constructed properly, for example (otherwise mma wouldn't know what to show when mouseover happens, I think):

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, .1}];
Graphics[Tooltip[Line[#]] & /@ Partition[data, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Alternatively you could add plot markers to enable the tooltips.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch thanks Mike, updated. +1 to you btw.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I added some thoughts in the answer.

Comment: The `Mesh` trick does not seem to work with `ListLinePlot3D`, but the `PlotMarkers` trick does. This can introduce significant slowdown though. (Version 13.0.1.0)

Answer (score 7):

As Vitaly has indicated, you need to have a point to tooltip over. Another approach is to add plot markers -- not suitable if a large number of points present:

```
data = Table[Tooltip[{x, x^2}], {x, 0, 10, .1}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

**Edit**

As per my conversation with Vitaly you can tooltip your line. I had forgotten about that.

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10, .1}];
ListLinePlot[Tooltip[data, "this line is my data"]]
```

Comment: I think ti works like this: `Graphics[{Tooltip[Line[RandomReal[1, {15, 2}]], "hello"]}]`

Comment: Yes you're right. I thought I'd tried that once and it didn;t work. oh well!